# Google Form Validate a specific URL Regex

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am creating a google form and trying to create a regex on of the fields because I need them to enter a profile link from a specific website.  I'm a beginner with regex and this is what I have come up with:

```
/^(http:\/\/)?(steamcommunity\.com\/id\/)*\/?$/
```

But when I go to enter a test link such as: http://steamcommunity.com/id/bagzli it fails it.  I don't understand what is wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate goal of what I was trying to accomplish is to ensure that certain text was entered in the box.  I thought I had to use Regex to accomplish that, but google forms also has "Text Contains" feature which I made use of to solve my problem.  The regex by Zoff Dino did not work, I am not sure why as it seems completely correct.

I will mark this as resolved as I managed to get my answer, even if it was not via regex.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a dot (meaning any character) after the `(/id\)`. Try this:

```
/^(http:\/\/)?(steamcommunity\.com\/id\/).*\/?$/
                                         ^-- added
```

Comment: I tried your version, still doesn't work with the above example.  Maybe Google forms regex has to be somehow different?